# How to store previously seen posts in infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, infinite-scroll

I am making a website (coded in reactjs with firebase/firestore as backend) where users can go through posts with infinite scrolling (like on tumblr). However, I am confused about how I should store posts that have already been loaded. I was thinking of storing them in an array as part of my component state, but I don't know how much data it's ok to store in state - after the user has been scrolling for a while there will be a lot of loaded posts that I have to store. Is there a better/more efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The infinity scroll performance issues won't be noticeable unless you expect your user to really scroll far down. There is not cap on how much data can be stored in the state, the cap is how much the user's computer can handle. There goes my 2 cents. Now I'll be interested to see if there is an efficient way on handling state data.

Comment: Do it the way you were planning. Then test it with the most extreme case you care about supporting. If it doesn't work well, then ask a more specific question at that point.

Comment: This should help: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-infinite-scroll/